# Removing single backslash from string

Tags: ios, swift

I am getting a string for a place name back from an API: `"Moe\'s Restaurant & Brewhouse"`. I want to just have it be `"Moe's Restaurant & Brewhouse"` but I can't get it to properly format without the `\`.

I've seen the other posts on this topic, I've tried `placeName?.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\\", withString: "")` and `placeName?.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\'", withString: "'")`. I just can't get anything to work. Any ideas so I can get the string how I want it without the `\`? Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!!

Comment: maybe use the ascii code?  String(UnicodeScalar(92))

Comment: When you say you get the string from an API, what kind of string object is it you get? Since `\'` is an escape character for swifts native `String`, your string `"Moe\'s Restaurant & Brewhouse"` will for all usage with native swift `String` be `"Moe's Restaurant & Brewhouse"`. Possibly give us some more context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You report that the API is returning `"Moe\'s Restaurant & Brewhouse"`. More than likely you are looking at a Swift dictionary or something like that and it is showing you the string literal representation of that string. But depending upon how you're printing that, the string most likely does not contain any backslash.

Consider the following:

```
let string = "Moe's"
let dictionary = ["name": string]
print(dictionary)
```

That will print:

> ["name": "Moe\'s"]

It is just showing the "string literal" representation. As [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH7-ID295) says:

> String literals can include the following special characters:
>
> - The escaped special characters `\0` (null character), `\\` (backslash), `\t` (horizontal tab), `\n` (line feed), `\r` (carriage return), `\"` (double quote) and `\'` (single quote)
> - An arbitrary Unicode scalar, written as `\u{n}`, where `n` is a `1`–`8` digit hexadecimal number with a value equal to a valid Unicode code point

But, note, that backslash before the `'` in `Moe\'s` is not part of the string, but rather just an artifact of printing a string literal with an escapable character in it.

If you do:

```
let string2 = dictionary["name"]!
print(string2)
```

It will show you that there is actually no backslash there:

> Moe's

Likewise, if you check the number of characters:

```
print(dictionary["name"]!.characters.count)
```

It will correctly report that there are only five characters, not six.

(For what it's worth, I think Apple has made this far more confusing than is necessary because it sometimes prints strings as if they were string literals with backslashes, and other times as the true underlying string. And to add to the confusion, the single quote character can be escaped in a string literal, but doesn't have to be.)

---

Note, if your string really did have a backslash in it, you are correct that this is the correct way to remove it:

```
someString.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\\", withString: "")
```

But in this case, I suspect that the backslash that you are seeing is an artifact of how you're displaying it rather than an actual backslash in the underlying string.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed and thoughtful response. You nailed it, definitely a bit confusing. Cheers!

Comment: I'm having some issues with this at the moment. If you print the dictionary key it will show the "clean" string (without backslashes, I have a `'` in there), but if you do some string interpolation with that string the backlash will still be there. Not to mention if you're using it in a path :D

Comment: did you solve this issue?

Comment: in my case, I have to send the dictionary values but dictionary values contain two slashes, I want to send the data only with a single slash, not two slashes.  I am not sure how to handle this case please suggest me a solution.

Comment: Nine times out of 10, there are not really two backslashes, but rather a single backslash, and the appearance of two backslashes is merely a function of how the string is displayed in Xcode (i.e., it is showing the string, sees a single backslash, and “escapes” the backslash just in the UI, but not in the underlying string).